# Visualizing a complex function

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

Ever since I learned about complex valued functions I've been wondering if there was a better visualization for them.  Obviously we can't visualize four dimensions, but I was wondering if it would be useful to model them as vector fields.  After all, a complex valued function is essentially a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Are there useful aspects of seeing it this way, and what benefits do other visualizations have over this?

Comment: It would be hard to visualize the branch cuts in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for some purposes this can be useful, as described (much better than I could do here) in Chapters 10 and 11 in the book [Visual Complex Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198534469) by Tristan Needham.